# It seems like my ajax call to url is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display a confirmation dialog to user before they delete a record in the database. I am developing this on my local PC webserver.
Sort of like this:
  user selects record for deletion(php form)
  user clicks delete button(php submit button)
  a dialog box pops up saying do you want to delete record(jquery)
    Yes - Ajax call to another php page in same directory

I've tried this with both chrome and FF with no errors that I can see other than the resulting page is never called.
FYI, The de.php page works fine if I call it directly through the browser like so:

```
http://localhost/de.php?eid=61
```

Here are some snippets:

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:340,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Delete Event": function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: '/de.php?eid=<?php echo $theEventId ?>',
        success: function(data) {
           alert('success');
        }, error: function (data) {
           alert('failed');
        }

      });
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      $('#myDiv').append('Trying to Delete');
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      $('#myDiv').append('Delete Cancelled');
    }
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

The form code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>" id="ee_form">

  <div id="myDiv"></div>

  <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update Event" />
  <a href="index.php"><input type="button" value="Cancel" /></a>      
  <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete Event <?php echo $theEventId ?>" />
</form>
```

The dialogue box comes up fine, with the correct eid.
If I select the "Delete Event" button I get a "success" alert, dialog closes, "Trying to Delete" is printed to the screen fine, but no indication that de.php was ever called.

Am I doing this correctly, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean there's no indication that the file was called, the success alert seems to indicate that it was called, what are you expecting ?

Comment: Use your developer tools (F12), in particular the Network tab if using Chrome, to find out whether the call has been successful or not.

Comment: Maybe you are confused because you are not updating the "Trying to Delete" message to something meaningful in the success handler. "Trying to delete" is probably written before the success handler is called due to the async nature of that ajax call.

Comment: When you say "the dialog comes up fine, **with the correct eid**, what do you mean? You can't be talking about the `eid` in the ajax url since that is **fixed** by `PHP` when the page loads.

Comment: I am looking at all the responses and they are all valid. They have me seeing the issue(s) a little better. In FF using F12 I can see that the actual eid is not being provided. The network GET response looks like this:  "de.php?eid=" So question now is, how do I get the eid value to show up in the url?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. As I mentioned in above message, in seeing the issue clearer now. I am in the habit of declaring my functions at the top and `$theEventId` had not been declared/defined yet. I see that moving the function lower in the process flow has fixed the issue. I am not sure how to leave this question so that people know this was the fix.

Answer (score -1):

Change the ajax section to post data.

Have the data in a form rather than echo'ing the JS.

```
<form id="myform">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $theEventId ?>">
 <button type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Then in the JS, serialize the form.

```
var form_data = $("#myform").serialize();
```

Then post the serialized data.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/de.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
           alert('success');
        }, error: function (data) {
           alert('failed');
        }

      });
```

Use developer tools in google chrome to see if anything was posted and what it is.

Comment: I tried, for a little bit, going down this path just to see and found a few things left out. I added them and got a little further but never did get it to even call the confirm dialogue code. I know I'm pretty close with my implementation above so will pursue that for now.

Comment: Show me what you have achieved and i'll try help? Did you make a form and serialize it? What did you get in Google chrome dev tools ?